# Tcl/Tk : Passing variable no. of arguments within tcl code

Tags: tcl, tcltk

```
set newarg [join $argmnts " "] 
set msg [exec $fname arguments]
```

Note : argmnts are not commandline arguments, it is from value_dialog_box

`newarg` is a list of arguments (no. of arguments may vary in `newarg`),
`fname` is some file name.
I want to pass these arguments (newarg) in `[exec $fname arguments]`

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [argument expansion](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9):

```
set msg [exec $fname {*}$argmnts]
```

which treats the elements of the list in `$argmnts` as individual arguments to `exec`.